# CORB error on video html tag blocking video content from displaying

Tags: javascript, html, video, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to build an embeddeable video frame to display video content on other pages. the video itself is being served from a certain location, and it plays fine with using `<iframe></iframe>` however I want this specific build of the video to be able to target a different src which is why i wanted to build it up with the video html tag instead of an iframe

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoPlay>
  <source src="https://embed.truthcasting.com/video/100003694/208448" type="video/mp4"/>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

the problem is the CORB error, however if i serve up the same content from an iframe

```
<iframe
  style={{ height: "25rem", width: "100%" }}
  scrolling="no"
  src="https://embed.truthcasting.com/video/100003694/208448"
  webkitallowfullscreen="true"
  mozallowfullscreen="true"
  allow="autoplay; fullscreen;encrypted-media;"></iframe>
```

the content will come through, no CORB error. Now normally I wouldnt mind and i would just use the iframe to display content, however i was hoping since with `<video>` you can designate multiple sources.

but no matter ive tried I cant seem to get around the CORB.. is this a server issue similar to CORS? do i need to add something somewhere in the server so it can display in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `video` html tag requires an actual video, the `src` url that was supplied to the HTML tag, is that to an external site, that plays a video, but isnt an actual video itself. the reason that it works on an `<iframe>` is because the iframe will display a webpage, `<video>` will not.